# Ping to bridge primary router is timing out

Tags: networking, dd-wrt

I have an [Linksys E900](http://www.linksys.com/en-eu/products/routers/e900) configured as a bridge. Basically it is connected wirelessly with my main Linksys router. I am using a direct ethernet connection from the Linksys E900 to an old PC that doesnt have wireless capabilities.

This configuration has been working fine for over a year now. All of a sudden I can’t seem to get internet from the router.

When checking the status `192.168.1.2` All seems to be fine and connected/active.

Ping to the router works:

```
PING 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.210 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.739 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.817 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.668 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.815 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.745 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.773 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.831 ms
C
--- 192.168.1.2 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.668/0.825/1.210/0.154 ms
```

Ping to the main router however is timing out:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 9
ping: sendto: Host is down
```

Connecting wirelessly directly to the main router from my cell phone works and could have access to the internet.

Any pointers on how I could proceed in my debug?

Comment: Yes. The phone is connected to the wireless network from the primary. No I can't ping or connect to 192.168.1.2 from my phone's browser. But I think that is expected?

Comment: It sounds like the e900 is no longer able to establish a wifi connection with the main router.  Have you rebooted everything?

Comment: Yes, I did reboot the E900 router multiple times. Do I still need to reboot the primary? The primary seems to be working fine with all other wireless devices.

Comment: It is worth a try.  Can you see the ssid in the dd-wrt tools of the E900?  There is a graph, and you can also see if the channel is saturated, which might also account for it if a neighbour is using the same channel.